# OpenThread otCoapSendRequest issue

Tags: coap, nrf52, openthread

I have started to work with OpenThread with a Nordic DK. 
I am working with the BLE/Thread coap example that I modified in order to be a FTD instead of a MTD. Also, on one of my devices, the CoAP is configured as a server.

I figured out that when I pushed the button nRF52840 DK board programmed as a CoAP server, the light of the other board changes which means that the *otCoapSendRequest* function works.

Isn't it supposed to only works on a client device ?

Is it a normal or just a small bug in the OpenThread function ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for OpenThread in particular, but it is common in CoAP that server functions are enabled in addition to client functions rather switching between client and server mode – so it's not unexpected that client features still work even though you enabled server features.

This is because CoAP is designed to have much code shared between client and server. The [Web of Things architecture](https://w3c.github.io/wot-architecture/) calls the resulting client-server nodes "servients" (server-clients).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. 
I dug into the Nordic Code and found out that the CoAP init function creats services if the server mode is enable. 
In my code I switch from server to client on a randomly elected main device and this switch seems not to remove the services, I guess this combine with what you said explains what I have.